# Gradle with no main class?

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to use Gradle without specifying a main class? I want to create a library and use gradle to manage my dependencies, and creating a main class doesn't make sense, but I can't seem to find any documents that don't say you need one.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you read that you needed a main class? To do what? I suggest you read the documentation of Gradle. Of course you can build a project which doesn't have a main class. Gradle builds your classes and doesn't care about the methods they contain.

Comment: Right here for one http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html. If I don't specify a main class and run gradlew build I get "Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.
> Unable to find main class"

Comment: You're looking at the doc for the plugin used to create an **application** (hence the name "application plugin"). By definition, a Java application needs a main class. If you're building a library, you have no reason to use this plugin.

Comment: Got ya, I'm using the spring-boot plugin, I'm guessing this inherits from the application plugin then

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using spring-boot gradle plugin to create a library, it maybe call task `bootRepackage` to find main class, that throw some error when the main class not found.

Use `bootRepackage.enabled` is work for me.

```
bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

If you using kotlin DSL like me, try `tasks`:

```
tasks.withType<RepackageTask> {
    enabled = false
}
```

Also:

```
val bootRepackage by tasks.getting {
    enabled = false
}
```

I am looking for a better answer on the spring boot gradle plugin, but not found temporarily.

Or, we can just use `spring-boot-dependencies` with `io.spring.dependency-management`, they will not append task `bootRepackage` to our projects.

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:X.Y.Z.RELEASE") }
}
```

But it is not good idea I think.

And, if you want upgrade spring boot version to `2.Y.Z.RELASE`, change `bootRepackage` to `bootJar`.

Comment: the problem happens with bootJar.enabled = false which what you want if you are using springboot for library and you don't want it to be packaged as boot runnable app, in addition to what @mirro-mutth said, you need to remove `id "org.springframework.boot" ` from your plugins and remove bootJar completely